# How to get string after second slash in url - using php?

Tags: php, string, url, character, slash

How to get string after second slash in url? URL is different every time (more slashes), but every time I need the whole text after the second slash. How to do it?

I am using this code:

```
<?php
    $str = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $last = substr($str, strrpos($str, '/') - 1);
    echo $last;
?>
```

...but it works online with some characters after slash.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: whats the output of raw `$str` anyway?

Comment: What are the slashes you're referring? the protocol one or subfolder/rewrites ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$last = explode("/", $str, 3);
echo $last[2];
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it - btw. is it safe?

Comment: sure but if you want, you can check it like "if(isset($last[2])){ //do sth }"

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    <?php
        $str = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $last = explode("/",$str,3);// so at second index rest of the string will come.
echo $last[2];
```

see here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = "google.com/whatever/hello";

    $last = GetStringAfterSecondSlashInURL($str);

    echo $last;

    function GetStringAfterSecondSlashInURL($the_url)
    {
        $parts = explode("/",$the_url,3);

        if(isset($parts[2]))
            return $parts[2];
    }

?>
```